# How can I cluster a set of queries with starting and ending times?

Tags: cluster-analysis, pattern-recognition

I'm given a set of queries q_1, q_2, ..., q_m. The query q_i for any 1<=i<=m can be executed several times in different times. I'm also given the starting and ending times of any execution of the query q_i.

Given the above information, I am interested in clustering queries such that a cluster consists of a set of queries that are ''often'' executed within some ''time gaps'' or distance. As it is shown in the following figure, for an example, we are given 5 queries with their execution time windows.

[image: A set of 5 queries and their execution time windows]

A feasible clustering algorithm outputs the following result.

[image: Resulting clusters]

Which clustering algorithms do you recommend for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Extract appropriate features.

Such as duration, frequency, cooccurrence.

Next, define a similarity function to*quantify* which queries are similar.

Then choose the algorithm based on that.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is a bit abstract. What I can see now is to somehow transform queries into a sequence of queries that captures "time windows/distances" as well as the co-occurrences of the queries. Next, apply RNN to predict or recognize patterns.